# Cannot get response from HttpClient

Tags: angular, observable, angular-httpclient

I have been trying to handle an error response from my API.

What I'm trying to get:

[image: dev tools showing expected error message]

What I'm actually getting:

[image: console log showing observable object]

my service.ts:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

private url = environment.urlServer;
constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient ) { }

guardarUsuario( data: {nombre: string, correo: string, pass: string, descripcion: string }) {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${ this.url }/usuario`, data).pipe(
        catchError((res: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(res);
            return throwError(JSON.stringify(res));
        
        })
    );
}
```

my component.ts:

```js
this.coreService.guardarUsuario( data )
    .subscribe( res => {
            console.log('Successfull response: ', res);
        }, err => {
          console.log('Error response', err);
        }
    );
```

Update:
Here´s the interceptor code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) { }

  intercept( req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token: string = sessionStorage.getItem('token');

    let request = req;

    if ( token ) {
      request = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${ token }`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.toastr.error(`Error: ${ err }`)
        }
        throw throwError( 'Auth error: ', err );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

This is my first time working with interceptors, the interceptor its already imported in the providers of the `app.module` too.
How can I get the error message from my API response in the error handler of my subscription?

Comment: Try not to return the throw..?

Comment: When you subscribe, the "error function" is executed when there an error in the call to the API (when the API return a not found, or not allowed or... -the 404, 401,500...-), not if the api return a result as you show. You get in "res" the object `{message:....}`: NOTE. you can use the response **inside** the subscribe function, not out of it, so you can, e.g. write `this.coreService.guardarUsuario(data).subscribe(res=>this.message=res.message},...)`

Comment: Your console log doesn't have the "Error response" or "Successfull response" text in it. Is there another console log you have?

Comment: The console.log in the image is from the console.log in the service.ts before returning the error

Comment: try removing the catchError since there is no action happening in there.
or in catchError do `throw new Error(JSON.stringify(res))` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its any use to someone i changed the `catchError` of the `interceptor` from:

```
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.toastr.error(`Error: ${ err }`)
        }
        throw throwError( 'Auth error: ', err );
      })
```

to:

```
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errorMsg = '';
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          errorMsg = `Error ${ error.error.message}`;
        } else {
          errorMsg = `Error code: ${error.status}, Message: ${error.message}`
        }
        return throwError(errorMsg);
      })
```

And the `httpRequest` to:

```
guardarUsuario( data: {nombre: string, correo: string, pass: string, descripcion: string }) {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${ this.url }/usuario`, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct `throwError`, it doesn't seem to be imported in your code e.g.

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

Also, you generally need to extract the message from the `HttpErrorResponse`, something like:

```
return throwError(res.error.message);
```

There's a mistake in the **interceptor**: `throw throwError(..)` should be `return throwError(...)`

Comment: I did import the throwError, i tried to extract the message as you said but  it's still not working

Comment: My apologies, I already updated the question and included the interceptor

Comment: Thank you! The  problem was in the catcError of the Interceptor!